# Give an example of a Rothberger space $X$ which has a subspace $Y$ that is not locally Lindelof.

Tags: general-topology

1. A space $X$ is called Rothberger if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(U_n)$ such that for each $n$ $U_n\in\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\{U_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover of $X$.
2. A space $X$ is called locally Lindelof if for each $x\in X$ there exist an open set $U$ and a Lindelof subspace $L$ such that $x\in U\subseteq L$.

Comment: What's your favourite example of a space that is not locally Lindelöf?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\mathbb{R}^2$ with radial interval topology (see http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4612-6290-9%2F1.pdf) is not locally Lindelof.